# Getting Error in w3c validator as No space between attributes for slider revolution plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In w3c validator checking, I got an error as no space between attributes. But those attributes are dynamically generated in the slider revolution plugin in WordPress. How to rectify this error?

Already I have checked in theme punch which is the provider of slider revolution plugin. They have said that in version 5.1.2 error is rectified. But I have version 5.4.8 still the error rises.

Comment: Provide the page link

Comment: Due, to some privacy I can't share the link. I took screenshot of my issue.kindly look on it (https://prnt.sc/n7ajbq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by disable the html minify in w3-total-cache plugin and it leads to some warning such as

> Remove type tag from script and style

and fixed this warning by adding this code in functions.php

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
ob_start( function( $buffer ){
    $buffer = str_replace( array( 'type="text/javascript"', "type='text/javascript'" ), '', $buffer );

    // Also works with other attributes...
    $buffer = str_replace( array( 'type="text/css"', "type='text/css'" ), '', $buffer );
    // $buffer = str_replace( array( 'frameborder="0"', "frameborder='0'" ), '', $buffer );
    // $buffer = str_replace( array( 'scrolling="no"', "scrolling='no'" ), '', $buffer );  
    return $buffer;
});});
```